# How to get values that contains specific string - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

guys, I would like to know how I can get values without writing a whole string.

Example: I have this name `Fulano Branco Cesar`;

I want to get this name when I write something like `Fulano Cesar` or `Branco Cesar` or `Fulano Branco`.

Today I have: `{ NAME: { like: 'Fulano Cesar', options: 'i' }` and it returning nothing to me..

I already used `regex`, `all` and `contains` function.

Like: `{ NAME: { regex: .*${NAME}.*, options: 'i' } }`.

Can someone help me ? PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

given

```
> db.names.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6027b60b4aff165418b35ff6"), "name" : "roger Cesar" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6027b60b4aff165418b35ff7"), "name" : "jules cesar" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6027b60b4aff165418b35ff8"), "name" : "nope" }
```

You may give a regex in your find predicate

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dummy')

const NameModel = mongoose.model('Name', { name:String }, 'names')


;(async()=>{
  try {
  mongoose.set('debug', true)
  console.log('names : ', await NameModel.find({ name: /Cesar/i }))

  /*
    names :  [
      { _id: 6027b60b4aff165418b35ff6, name: 'roger Cesar' },
      { _id: 6027b60b4aff165418b35ff7, name: 'jules cesar' }
    ]
  */
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }
})()
```

Then it is just basic js if you want to specify any regex

```
const findName = name => {
  return NameModel.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') })
}
await findName('Cesar')
```

Comment: thank so much for your help, it worked.. but I have a question.

I have this register: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("6027b60b4aff165418b35ff6"), "name" : "Joao Pereira Silva" }`

How can I found this just writing: `Joao Silva` ?

Comment: You have to specify regex: ```/Joao.*Silva/``` (with possibly the i flag if case isensitive). (e.g: replacing whitespaces by ```.*``` ```....find({name: new RegExp(str.replace(/\s+/,'.*'), 'i')```}) )(PS: in mongo the vocabulary is document or record, not register)